# AndroidTV HeaderItem icon can't be set

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-tv

With the sparse documentation and examples available I am having severe difficulties to get icons working in HeaderItems.

None of the existing documentation and samples actually show a working example of setting the imageUri string as part of the 3rd parameter of the HeaderItems constructor. They just all pass in null like this

```
HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(i, "Category " + i, null);
mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));
```

So given that I have the Uri below... (which is a working Uri)

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.justeat.app.uk/" + R.drawable.tv_category_dot);
```

I have tried the following without success

```
HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(0, listHeader, uri.toString());
```

Because of the lack of documentation and source code available I have been unable to figure out why this isnt enough. If anyone has any other ideas please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried with a random image, pulled from the web? I believe the problem might be the protocol you're using (android.resource). E.g., https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-gear-a-128.png

Comment: This API is not presently recommended and currently being worked on.